# PL/SQL Script - first timer

Tags: plsql

I have data in an interface table that I need to copy over to the application table based on a set of criteria (project #, task_Number). I am able to access everything I need in a select statement. I am unsure of how to start the script. Any pointers would be wonderful. I havent written a PL/SQL script before.

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or something that will be run regularly? If the latter, how is it to be called? By the same process that loads data into the interface table or via a scheduled job (e.g. every 2 hours / once a day / etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to PLSQL!

How you write your script depends on the context from which it will be run.

If I am running a script through sqlplus I have some bolier plate which I have below which you might find starts you off.

```
set define off;
set serveroutput on;
declare
  l_error varchar2(4094);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Start of script named XXX');

  --Select/Insert statements here

  --commit

  dbms_output.put_line('End of script named XXX');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  l_error := NVL(SUBSTR(SQLERRM,0,990),'NULL');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_error || ':-' || NVL(SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE,0,3000),'NULL')); 
  rollback;
end;
```